# RabbitMq connection timeout exception

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Using spring amqp (rabbitmq):

My consumer takes quite a lot of time to process message sometimes my business logic takes more than 2 hours but then after the processing when I try to acknowledge the rabbitmq for "basic ack" it throws connection timeout exception.

What should I do ? Should I make connection live forever or use heartbeats ?

Answer (score 0):

If your logic definitely is based on MANUAL ack, you indeed don't have choice unless make your connections long living. Heartbeat should be there by default anyway.

Otherwise consider the solution with the AUTO ack and in case of errors afterward downstream just send messages back to the queue for retying in the future.

Comment: The connection should remain open, as long as heartbeats are configured (which they are by default). However, it's rather unusual to hold a message in such a state for so long. It's an anti-pattern for messaging; it's generally better to persist long-running tasks in a persistent store such as a database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an alternative option with ack-ing right after your long-lasting business operation starts and later informing about its status: either failure or success, in case if you have any dependent actors.

As Artem & Gary suggest that it's quite an anti-pattern to hold messages for a long time, you may want to make the process really async -- your service consumed a message and started doing some stuff: good then, let's acknowledge that. And in case if you need to repeat on failure, just make a separate message once failure appears, so another consumer would take it and process it.